# Sorting(rearranging) the list

Tags: python

I have been struggling to sort  or rearrange the lists. I would want to sort the lists in descending order based on the numbers(last element within the list). 
So, ideally, the list with (297539) will be on top; while the list with (234933) will be at bottom:

```
[...., '297539']
[..]
[..]
[...., '234933']
```

Can someone help me with this? Thanks alot.
This is what I have done so far[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7IXY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `itemgetter` you can handle loop

```
from operator import itemgetter
a = [['a', '297539'],['sas', '257539'],['absdas', '287539'],['xasd', '234933']]
a = sorted(a, key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
print(a)
```

Comment: itemgetter is better than using a lambda function , good solution, no idea why you recive a negative upvote

Comment: Not me @prashantrana, but the problem I see here is that, as mentioned as a comment this is sorting lexicographically (as the numbers are strings), meaning that when sorting numbers `'9' > '12'`, which presumably is not what OP wants?

Comment: @yatu, i didn't try that out. you are right this method failed in that case. `sorted(a,key =lambda x:int(itemgetter(1)(x)))`  improvement to existing solution. using lambda i guess your answer is much better .

Answer (score 3):

Use `sorted` with a custom `key` function:

```
# example list
l = [['a', '297539'],['sas', '257539'],['absdas', '287539'],['xasd', '234933']]
sorted(l, key=lambda x: int(x[-1]), reverse=True)
# [['a', '297539'], ['absdas', '287539'], ['sas', '257539'], ['xasd', '234933']]
```

Comment: How is `int` redundant @Nihal? strings are sorted lexicographically, i.e.`'9' > '12'`, so the numbers must be turned to ints, otherwise only the first digit is considered

Comment: you are right, sry my mistake

Comment: you can also use `sorted(a,key =lambda x:int(itemgetter(1)(x)))`

Comment: `itemgetter` is interesting when it can be used to avoid a `lambda` function, as operations are kept on the `C` side, which is not this case @prashantrana